# asp.net confirm delete action conditionally

Tags: jquery, asp.net

In a Asp.net page I have a grid of departments that is displayed with checkboxes that can be checked to delete departments. If the selected record(department) has child records (Employees) I need to confirm the delete - otherwise I will delete the records without confirmation.
What is the standard and most elegant way to perform this
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few links which are useful for you.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/GridViewConfirmDelete.aspx

http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/fritz/archive/2006/03/22/20514.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/02/434362.aspx

http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/adding-a-gridview-column-of-checkboxes-cs

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/SelChkboxesDataGridView.aspx

Comment: I Checked those - none of these is a conditional confirm.The confirm is always called

Comment: You can keep a hidden field in the template for every row and set its value if the row is having children, then based on that value you can display the warning message.